# AspNetBoilerplate: Use single authentication provider for multiple applications

Tags: authentication, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate

We have multiple ASP Net Boilerplate applications and we are trying to use a single authentication provider for all of them, in a way that we can get a bearer token from an authentication API and use the same token for each application.

The documentation about External Authentication doesn't seem to cover this, and I haven't been able to find additional information regarding this.

Is there a way to implement this? Or maybe something similar to what we are looking for?

Comment: You should consider using a token provider like https://duendesoftware.com/ or Auth0 to issue tokens for your applications.

Comment: @ToreNestenius We already have a token provider for other applications that we can use, the issue is that I can't seem to find documentation on implementing it on ASP Net Boilerplate applications instead of their own internal authentication.